# Can't Sync Google Calendar

Tags: applications, backup, samsung

I have an error while synchronizing my Google Calendar on my Samsung Note N7000 with Android 4.1.2, my Google accout does never Sync

I have a whole load of important meetings that go back to 2014, which are very very important to me.
I want to sync these datas to my GMail account via my calendar on my phone.

However, if I sync my Calendar with my Google Account on the Note, the Sync Fails saying 'sync is currently experiencing problems. it will be back shortly'

Using Samsung Kies does not work because the meetings that Kies syncs are only the one one the Samsung Calendar Applcation. Not the ones I've set up in my Gmail on my phone.

How could I go past this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the Google account and adding it again.

Comment: This seems more to be a comment than an answer.

Comment: In my experience this often solved the problem, so I think it's fine as an answer.

Comment: Well, I will loose my calendar informations then, won't I ? My Calendar is not synced. I fear deleting the account and recreating it will delete everything